# Does a static field outlive the containing instance? Is this a memory leak?

Tags: java, performance, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I am using a library as part of my application.
I am instantiating a class that is imported from this library. E.g. `Calculator c = new Calculator()` and use the instance.
The class `Calculator` has a static member field which is a hash map `internalMap` with strong references to objects. I am referring to the key/value pairs.
So while I use the instance `c` this static `internalMap` is getting populated (by the internal logic of this library not by my code).
What I am not sure about is whether this static hashmap outlives the instance.
I think that if `c` is GCed the static `internalMap` will not be GCed because it is static.
So essentially this memory is being "lost"? I.e a memory leak?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. You will have to clean up any statics you have if you want to reclaim that memory. Perhaps the author of the library has already provided some way of handling this?

Comment: No the class is not exposed to client code. So if the hashmap had key/values that were weak references there would not be an issue right? Also even if the keys/values are only referenced by the hashmap they remain permanently because hashmap is not GCed right?

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of some method provided by the library to clean up the mess. Anyway, I'm guessing weak references would not be an issue, except that the map itself would still exist. And yes, everything referenced within the map will remain.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the GC (Garbage Collector) looks at heap memory and identify which objects are in use (and which are not)...deleting the unused objects. If an object is being used/referenced, it means that "somebody" still maintains a pointer to it. On the other hand, an unused/unreferenced object that's no longer referenced, it's ready to release the memory used when the GC runs.

Based on that, for your `Calculator` class, whenever you have references in the `internalMap` and the GC runs, it won't be released...at all. So it's not that "it outlives the instance", the instance will be there until it gets GC'ed, but because it still has a (or more) member(s) that has some "active" references it cannot be GC'ed (thus, the memory occupied by it cannot be reused/freed).

Correct me if I'm wrong...